# g++ Rcpp Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on osx

Tags: macos, g++, rcpp

I am trying to create a dylib file in OSX El Capitain from a C++ source file to read into R via Rcpp. Here is a grossly simplified example of what I've created:

```
//test.cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP dosum(SEXP _a, SEXP _b){
   double a = Rcpp::as<double>(_a);
   double b = Rcpp::as<double>(_b);
   return Rcpp::wrap(a+b);
}
```

When I compile/link using the following Makefile on a Linux server that is available to me at my university,

```
CC=g++
# note the use of c++14, used to use c++11

all: test

test : 
${CC} -DNDEBUG \
    -I. \
    -I/usr/share/R/include \
    -I/server/linux/lib/R/3.0/x86_64/site-library/Rcpp/include \
    -I/usr/share/Rcpp_0.12.3/include \
    -fpic  -O3 -pipe \
    -std=c++1y \
    -c test.cpp
${CC} -shared -o test.so test.o

clean:
    @find . \( -name "*.o" -o -name "*.so" \) -exec rm {} \;
```

I get the desired `test.so` file, which I can then read in during an R session via `dyn.load('test.so')`. Once it has been loaded, I can use the function `dosum()` via `dosum(x,y)`. Great.

But I would like to do the exact same thing in OSX El Capitain on my personal Mac. I have tried many variations of a Makefile, and am currently using,

```
CC=g++

all: temp

temp: 
    ${CC}  \
            -I. \
            -I/usr/share/R/include \
            -I/usr/local/include/Rcpp/Rcpp_0.12.5/inst/include \
            -fPIC \
            -c temp.cpp
    ${CC} -dynamiclib  *.o -o  temp.dylib

clean:
    @find . \( -name "*.o" -o -name "*.dylib" \) -exec rm {} \;
```

When I run this Makefile, I get the following,

```
g++  \
    -I. \
    -I/usr/share/R/include \
    -I/usr/local/include/Rcpp/Rcpp_0.12.5/inst/include \
    -fPIC \
    -c temp.cpp
g++ -dynamiclib  *.o -o  temp.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_REprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long) in temp.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::overflow(int) in temp.o
  "_R_FlushConsole", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::sync() in temp.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::sync() in temp.o
  "_R_GetCCallable", referenced from:
      dataptr(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
  "_R_NilValue", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rcpp_protect(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
      Rcpp::Shield<SEXPREC*>::~Shield() in temp.o
  "_Rf_allocVector", referenced from:
      SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::primitive_wrap__impl__cast<double>(double const&, Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, false>) in temp.o
  "_Rf_coerceVector", referenced from:
      SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::basic_cast<14>(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
  "_Rf_length", referenced from:
      double Rcpp::internal::primitive_as<double>(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
  "_Rf_protect", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rcpp_protect(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
  "_Rf_unprotect", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Shield<SEXPREC*>::~Shield() in temp.o
  "_Rprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::xsputn(char const*, long) in temp.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::overflow(int) in temp.o
  "_TYPEOF", referenced from:
      SEXPREC* Rcpp::r_cast<14>(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
      SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::basic_cast<14>(SEXPREC*) in temp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [temp] Error 1
```

That is, it appears that things are getting garbled and an underscore is being added at the front of the variables in question. What am I doing wrong? I have tried adding/dropping various flags like `-fpic`, `-std=XXX` and so on.

I have found related questions, but they appear to be cases where the original poster is confusing how to use Rcpp in the first place. Here, I just want to do on the Mac what I can do in Linux. I have no reason to believe that there is a fundamental difference between the header files on my Mac versus those on the Linux box, but I have not yet checked in detail.

FWIW, I **can** create dylibs using the same approach on my Mac as long as they don't use Rcpp (for example, a simple `cout << "hello world" <<endl;` function), so maybe my Rcpp installation is somehow messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `Makefile`?

It all works if you just let R do its business.  Here is one-to-four-liner (depending on how you count):

```
R> cppFunction("SEXP dosum(SEXP a_, SEXP b_){
   double a = Rcpp::as<double>(a_);
   double b = Rcpp::as<double>(b_);
   return Rcpp::wrap(a+b);
}")
R> dosum(4, 7)
[1] 11
R>
```

Note, however, that I had to revert your *invalid* identifier `_a, _b` to valid `a_, b_`.

All this can of course also be had as a one-liner given the templated conversions we get for free:

```
R> cppFunction("double dosum2(double a, double b) { return a+b; }")
R> dosum2(5, 8)
[1] 13
R>
```

Comment: Yes, I was aware that I could use cppFunction but my real code is thousands of lines long split over many different files. It even includes a Fortran routine. Is it still possible/appropriate to use cppFunction in that case? And is it not true that the code needs to be recompiled each time the program is run?

Comment: In short: build a package.  You never want a Makefile, because it is too easy to get wrong.  As you did here.